# Tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tooltip

Since

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notice').tooltip();
});
```

doesn't work for me - probably because I am loading the element with the class `.notice` dynamically with Ajax - I have tried to go ahead with another way. So this is what I have so far:

```
$(document.body).on("mouseover", ".notice", function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

This makes it work but it causes two problems:

1. The first time when I hover the element, nothing happens (even no error in the console) but the second time when I hover it, tooltip works!
2. At the second time when I hover the element, I see the tooltip box and the title box. See image bellow.

   [image]

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to init tooltip when you're creating new ".notice" element.

e.g.

`$(document.body).tooltip();`

Comment: What does that mean? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: In your ajax success function, when you append your new `.notice` elements, call the `.tooltip()` function for each one.

Comment: When you create a new object with .notice class in your create function call the .tooltip() on it and delete this line from your code: $(document.body).on("mouseover", ".notice", function() { ....

Answer (score 1):

For delegated tooltip functionality you can simply attach handler to parent container, then all inner elements with title attributes will get custom tooltips:

```
$(document.body).tooltip();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/off074wb/